# Need help with function calling

Tags: c++

This is my first year studying I.T. and c++ so I don't have much of any knowledge in c++. The question is about function calling.

**The Function Header is:**

```
bool insure(int age, bool smoker)
```

My task is to write down the correct function call and declare all the variables that I will use in the calling statement.

So far, this is what I've come up with:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool insure(int age, bool smokers)
{
    bool ret;
}
int main ()
{
    int age;
    bool isSmoker;
    bool ret;

    cout << "Enter your age: ";
    cin >> age;
    ret = insure(age, isSmoker);

    return 0;
}
```

I'd like to know if this program is correct or if I'm doing something wrong. Thanks in advance

Comment: What happened when you ran it?

Answer (score 7):

You're not returning anything from `insure`, and you're passing it an uninitialized variable (`isSmoker`).  And you're not verifying that the input worked: what happens if the user enters "abc" for his age.

Comment: Good on yer to mention error handling. I assumed he assumed correct input always.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool insure(int age, bool smokers)
{        
    if(age>=25&&smokers==true)return true;
    else return false;
}

int main ()
{        
    int age=25;
    bool isSmoker=true;
    bool ret;

    cout << "Enter your age: ";
    cin >> age;
    ret = insure(age, isSmoker);
    cout<<"Insure:"<<ret;

    return 0;
}
```

This code block is written assuming that insurance is true for people aged 25 yrs or more and smoker.  You can change the logic inside the `insure(age,smokers)` function.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything fundamentally too wrong with it, although:

1. You don't return anything from `insure`. Is this by design? Maybe you want to add `return ret`?
2. You don't define starting values for any of your variables. This is bad form and may cause undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The task sounds like you are to take `bool insure(int age, bool smoker)` as a black box and show how to call it.  So I suppose the first question you need to answer for yourself is whether or not you are required to actually write a definition of `insure` or just have to show how you would use the function.  Once you've resolved that,

- How many and what types of variables does `insure` require?
- What does `insure` return and how do you store it?
- How do you set up/initialize the variables you have to use for calling it and holding the value is returns?
- What sorts of error checking should you do to make sure you're passing "good" values to `insure`?  (Has your class covered error-checking and error-handling yet?)